# Is my CPU broken? WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I have been having problems with my PC BSOD-ing pretty often when I am playing games. The error it is giving me on the BSOD itself is the WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR, which as Google revealed means a hardware error. So that is not good.

I have been able to procure 2 seperate memory dumps, one being auto-created and the other being a full memory dump. Both memory dumps were obtained after attempting to play COD: MW Beta, with the BSOD appearing as soon as I matchmade into a game.

Small MemDump: https://pastebin.com/B9suMeFJ 
Complete MemDump: https://pastebin.com/F6xYsNi0

From what I can tell these MemDumps indicate issues with the processor, so I am starting to worry that either my CPU itself or the RAM is broken. I cannot accurately tell if this is the root cause or not, as I am having trouble decrypting the MemDump syntax.

I find it weird that this only seems to occur when I put my PC under load (playing games, ie COD: MW Beta & Rainbow Six Siege), though, as I can do any other tasks (Visual Studio, 20+ Youtube tabs) without any crashes. I have previously encountered this issue as well whilst playing Rainbow Six Siege, but this would occur seldomly and as such I could not pinpoint the exact issue. I have attempted to de-encrypt the memory dumps before after this happened, but could never determine the root cause.

To resolve this I have taken apart my PC and taken out the RAM + GPU to clean it with compressed air. Afterwards I have used Driver Booster 6 through Steam to find any drivers that I might have forgotten to update, as well as verifying that I had the latest Nvidia GPU drivers for my GPU.

I am currently setting up to apply synthetic loads to my PC, using MemTest86 first to verify the RAM itself and I am going to use Prime95 + 3DMark after to see what the CPU does under load. However, if someone could give me insight into what errors the MemDumps hold I would massively appreciate it :)

UPDATE: I just finished running the Intel Processor Diagnostic Test Tool (IPDTT?) and that finished without any issues, so I am even more confused as to what is actually causing this.

UPDATE 2: I have run the MemTest86 and all the synthetic load stress tests in the Intel Extreme Tuning software, which all went off without any hitches. Per John's suggestion I have verified that I have no pending Windows updates, and I will be checking the Vendor (MOBO) drivers to see if those are indeed up to date.

Comment: If you have not physically removed the CPU from its socket then it's unlikely the CPU that is damaged.  I assume this problem is new, and the problems started, before any troubleshooting was attempted.

Comment: Yes, it is a new problem now that it occurs this often, though in the past weeks I have seen it occasionally crash whilst playing Rainbow Six Siege. I swear it had some memdumps saved, but unfortunately I could not retrieve those.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible it is not a hardware problem. Follow this Microsoft Article below:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028662/windows-how-to-fix-wheauncorrectableerror

Also update all your drivers with the Manufacturer's Driver Update Program.

The two things above together may help. Then if not, a hardware error looms more likely

Comment: I am starting to think you might be on to something, I have run all the Intel Extreme Tuning stress tests (CPU, RAM, GPU) so far and they have all worked without a hitch. I would be quite surprised if this was because of a Windows Update though or a Vendor error. I will verify that I have the latest MOBO driver version upgrades though, though given that the last releases for my GA-Z97X Gaming 7 MOBO were in 2016 I do not hold much hope :(

Comment: Since you have done some hardware tests, try what I suggested above

Comment: I have verified that I have all MOBO latest drivers installed, as well as running Driver Booster again. I also had no windows updates available, yet sadly it still is BSOD-ing in the same way.

Comment: It would appear you have a hardware problem. If you can, try memory with just one module at a time to see if it might be memory .  Otherwise, there is apparently a problem with the motherboard or CPU. You may now need to get it serviced or consider replacing the computer.

Comment: But should it then also not conk out whilst under the synthetic loads / benchmarks if that was the issue?

Comment: Could be temperature going up that causes that

Comment: The only other thing to suggest if you think it is not a hardware issue is to back up everything, install Windows fresh, wait a half day or so and begin adding software slowly until an application causes an issue

Comment: I have ran some more stress tests and it does not appear that it is temperature that is causing the issue, as the PC sat chugging for 3+ hours just fine with HeavyLoad and afterwards with Furmark. I have since attempted a clean install with the minimal amount of installed software: just the LAN driver, nvidia drivers and the battlenet launcher with COD MW beta itself. It still yields the same problematic crashing: does that mean my MOBO, CPU and RAM are a writeoff?

Comment: Given all you have done, there is a major hardware issue. You need to determine whether it is economical to repair or you need to replace the computer